$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x\log x}{x}dx$
I have found a method to solve for the value of the integral
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x\log x}{x}dx$$ I found a few solutions online and many of them, and many are quite similar to my solution, but my solution seems to go into a much simpler result, which doesn't seem to match.
Consider $$I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-ax}\log x}{x}dx$$ Then the required integral $I$ is given by $$I=\frac{I(-i)-I(i)}{2i}$$ Differentiating $I(a)$ wrt $a$ under the integral sign, we get $$\frac{dI}{da}=-\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}\log x dx=\frac{\gamma+\log a}{a}$$ which can be proved by considering the Laplace Transform of the power function $\int_0^\infty e^{-st}t^a dt=\frac{\Gamma(a+1)}{s^{a+1}}$ and then differentiating wrt a under the integral sign.
Integrating $\frac{dI}{da}$ wrt $a$ we get $$I(a)=\gamma\log a+\frac1{2}\log^2 a+C$$ giving us $$I=\gamma\left(\log(-i)-\log(i)\right)+\frac1{2}\left(\log^2(-i)-\log^2(i)\right)=-\frac{\gamma\pi}{2}$$ which seems to be the right answer. Did I go wrong somewhere? Most answers I saw considered $$I(a)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x\log x}{x}e^{-ax}dx$$ which made the calculation a bit more involved, and I don't see why this is necessary.

You used $\sin{x} = \frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$. Then consider another integral $\mathcal{I}(a)$ to eliminate $x$ from the denominator but others wrote $I(a) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin{x} \log{x}}{x} e^{-ax}$ See $I(1) = I$ so they differentiate I(a) in order to get I. Basically both are the same method!

@LuckyChouhan I did think the methods are quite similar but their method required a lot more work and a limit at the end to get the value of the integral, which makes me feel like my method is not as rigorous...

Are you taking about this integral? PS: I didn't downvote your question. I don't know why you got one downvote :(

@LuckyChouhan I am yeah, their solution is so much more complicated
and I don't see a downvote lmao

@LuckyChouhan and @ the OP too: IDK what happened to that $+C$, but $I(i)$ and $I(-i)$ diverge. If you use the definition of improper integrals to split up one of your integrals into two limits of integrals and expand the integrand as a series centered at $x=0$, you'd see that the first term is $\frac{\ln x}{x}$, which is not improperly integrable on $[0,c)$ for all $c>0$.

@Accelerator oh yeah! You're right because $|e^{ix}| = 1$ so $I(i)$ and $I(-i)$ are both $\leq \int_0^\infty \frac{\log{x}}{x} \mathrm{d}x$ Thank you!! so the correct approach is to introduct $e^{-ax}$ in the integrand?

@LuckyChouhan No, I'm not bounding anything. I'm just using this definition and expanding the integrand as a series. There's a non-integrable singularity at $x=0$ for $\frac{e^{ix}\ln x}{x}=\frac{\cos x\ln x}{x}+\frac{i\sin x\ln x}{x}$, and that's because of $\frac{\cos x\ln x}{x}$ having that non-integrable singularity despite $\frac{i\sin x\ln x}{x}$ having an integrable singularity at $x=0$. Whichever you introduce your $I(a)$ to be doesn't matter as long as you follow the Leibniz integral rule correctly and recover the integral you want.
